# Reconnecting to Selenium started PhantomJS

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

Hi I'm trying to minimise the amount of restarts I have to make when grabbing screenshots of websites.

Lets say I use this (get1.py)

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
driver.save_screenshot('screen.png')
exit()
```

Without the .close(), .quit() phantomJS will continue running in the background (on OSX anyway).

Now, I would like to reconnect back to that same driver that's running in the background and provide it another URL to screenshot.

Open once use many times!

Any ideas on the reconnection code?

Comment: Can you share your research/work?

Comment: Your question is not clear. The link you shared does not seems to be related to your question. Do you want take screenshot after each test without closing the browser or you want to do multiple functionality test without closing the browser or something else. Please clarify

Comment: Edited. I'm wanting to minimise the amount of driver start ups because I'm initiating it in one process, but then providing tasks (URLs to screenshot) from another, hence wanting to connect to the already existing process (and not have the overhead of starting it up each time)